# Does the SQL-1992 standard restrict naming identifiers to 18 characters?

Tags: naming-convention, sql-standard, identifier

In [this draft of SQL:1992](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), I found…

Section 5.2

> Leveling Rules
>
> ....
>
> 2. The following restrictions apply for Entry SQL in addition to any Intermediate SQL restrictions:
>
>    a) No `<regular identifier>` or `<delimited identifier body>` **shall contain more than 18 `<character representation>`s**.

…and…

> Annex A.1
>
> 1. Subclause 5.2, "`<token>` and `<separator>`":
>
>    a) In conforming Intermediate SQL language, a `<regular identifier>` or a `<delimited identifier body>` **shall not comprise more than 18 `<character representation>`s.**
>
>    b) A `<delimiter token>` shall not be a `<bit string literal>` or a `<hex string literal>`.
>
>    c) Conforming Intermediate SQL language shall contain no `<identifier body>` that ends in an `<underscore>`.

### For *implementors* of SQL, or for *users* of SQL?

I searched the document multiple times, but could never get a sense of the meaning of `identifier`.

- Is the spec referring to labeling within an *implementation* of SQL (such as PostreSQL or Oracle)? So labels used within the SQL product cannot contain identifiers that are over 18 characters or end in an underscore.
- Or is the spec referring to *users* of a SQL implementation? So we who are naming our schemas, tables, columns, and other such database objects cannot use names over 18 characters or end in an underscore?

Answer (score 1):

**Unless you're implementing SQL-1992's "Full SQL" (which is the 1992 spec), you should not have identifiers with more than 18 characters.**

SQL 1992 defines three levels of compatibility,

- **Entry SQL** includes the statements for defining schemas, data ma- nipulation language, referential integrity, check constraints, and default clause from ISO/IEC 9075:1989, and options for module lan- guage and embedded SQL interfaces to seven different programming languages, as well as direct execution of the data manipulation statements. It also includes features related to deprecated fea- tures from ISO/IEC 9075:1989 (commas and parentheses in parameter lists, the SQLSTATE parameter, and renaming columns in the ), features related to incompatibilities with ISO/IEC 9075:1989 (colons preceding s, WITH CHECK OPTION constraint clarifications), and aids for transitioning from ISO/IEC 9075:1989 to this International Standard (s).  Finally, it contains changes to correct defects found in ISO/IEC 9075:1989 (see Annex F, "Maintenance and interpretation of SQL").
- **Intermediate SQL** includes major new facilities such as statements for changing schemas, dynamic SQL, and isolation levels for SQL- transactions. It also includes multiple-module support and cascade delete on referential actions, as well as numerous functional en- hancements such as row and table expressions, union join, character string operations, table intersection and difference operations, simple domains, the CASE expression, casting between data types, a diagnostics management capability for data administration and more comprehensive error analysis, multiple character repertoires, interval and simplified datetime data types, and variable-length character strings. It also includes a requirement for a flagger facility to aid in writing portable applications.
- **Full SQL** increases orthogonality and includes deferred constraint checking and named constraints. Other technical enhancements in- clude additional user options to define datetime data types, self-referencing updates and deletes, cascade update on referen- tial actions, subqueries in check constraints, scrolled cursors, character translations, a bit string data type, temporary tables, additional referential constraint options, and simple assertions.

At the top you're quoting **"Entry SQL"** which though stricter is a "low" level of SQL conformance with the 1992 spec. This mode was for backwards compatibility with SQL:89 and the spec is pretty explicit

> ... [boring stuff] aids for transitioning from ISO/IEC 9075:1989 to this International Standard (s).

While I couldn't personally [dig up the SQL-89](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/205482/2639) standard, I assume it does have an 18 character limit on identifiers.

The other part is alarming to me, because I believe this shouldn't apply to **Intermediate SQL** from the spirit of the spec which is defined as,

But none the less, the spec is the letter of the law. Clearly even in **Intermediate SQL** the `<regular identifier>` and `<delimited identifier body>` should not be more than 18 characters.