# What is the formal SQL:2016 definition of a SQL identifier?

Tags: sql-standard

What is the formal definition of a SQL identifier in the ISO/IEC 9075:2016 standard?

Most specifically, in the case of both regular and delimited identifiers, what limitations exist on:

- Character set (UTF8?)
- First character set
- Subsequent character set
- Length limits

Answer (score 4):

You can look up the rules e.g. [here](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2016-foundation-grammar.html#_5_4_names_and_identifiers)

So a "regular" (i.e. "non-delimited") identifier must start with a [<simple Latin letter>](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2016-foundation-grammar.html#simple-Latin-letter)  which is essentially only the characters a-z (either upper or lower case).

Then it maybe followed by an [<SQL language identifier part>](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2016-foundation-grammar.html#SQL-language-identifier-part) which is either a `<simple Latin letter>` or a `<digit>` or the `<underscore>`

To sum it up: a regular identifier must start with a letter from a-z, and can only contain letters, digits (0-9) and the underscore.

A regular expression to validate a simple identifier would be: `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`

Mandating "simple latin letters" makes any multi-byte character set (e.g. UTF-8) invalid for use with a simple identifier.

Other character (e.g. a space) can only be used when using a "delimited" (aka "quoted") identifier which is enclosed in double quotes, e.g. `"%foo bar$"`. As far as I know this is also true for multi-byte characters.

The allowed length of an identifier is discussed in this question: [Does the SQL-1992 standard restrict naming identifiers to 18 characters?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204668/does-the-sql-1992-standard-restrict-naming-identifiers-to-18-characters)